# Webkit won't switch out background-image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, image, background

```
            function set_preview_image(image_link){
                $('#slideshow-container').css("background-image", "url('files/images/store/content/templates/websites/preview_images/" + image_link + "'");
            }
```

I'm passing through an image variable. Everything works fine in FF and IE. What am I missing? I've already tried using `backgroundImage` instead, and not using quotes within the url line...

Comment: You forgot a bracket at the end of the `url(` bit.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. You should have answered! I would've given you the green checkmark love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using wedkit's dev tools to see if why the background-image is not being applied.

BTW, it is not necessary to put a string param on `url()` and you missed a `)` at the end.

```
function set_preview_image(image_link){
    $('#slideshow-container').css("background-image", "url(files/images/store/content/templates/websites/preview_images/" + image_link +")");
}
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the help. You get a cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting // or ~/ in front of your url?  I've found that can help

Comment: You are a high-rep user, why did you do this?

Comment: I agree with iharob, this should have been a comment.

Comment: @iharob You'll notice this answer was posted over 5 years ago. SO was a different place back then, and the OP has likely leant to provide better answers since.